# Wordpress wp_enqueue_script() NEVER works

Tags: jquery, wordpress, include, wordpress-theming

I've read all the posts and the documentation on wp_enqueue script... but I've NEVER successfully gotten it to work.

This is what I'm doing that works:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MY CODE
</script>
```

I know I know I know this isn't the right way to to do it. So here's what I've tried instead:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_head();
```

No luck.

```
add_action('init', 'addscripts');
function addscripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 }
wp_head();
```

No luck.

```
//in the theme's functions.php file
add_action('init', 'addscripts');
//add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addscripts'); //this also doens't work
function addscripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 }
```

I've also tried the same approaches with the link to the external jquery library at google instead of the `jquery` tag. I've also tried de-registering and then registering the jquery script. Never works.

So I think these are the key questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my call to the `wp_enqueue_script()` function?
2. Where should it go? `functions.php`? `header.php`?
3. Is there a specific hook that I need to be using that's not mentioned? `'init'`? `'template_redirect'`? `'wp_enqueue_scripts?'`?

Please, no copy/pasted snippets from the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)! I've read it 50 times and tried them all. I promise.

I'm experimenting with a clean installation of WP3 and adding the above code to the default twentyeleven theme.

Comment: I don't know what you want from us.  All three of the questions you added with your last edit have their answers at [Wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: I'm the first to tell people to "RTFM" but that's not the problem in this case. The codex is extremely unclear on this topic. The documentation is sparse, and there is a TON of conflicting information elsewhere. That being said... I think I solved my problem (see my answer below).

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  Your solution contains information that would be most helpful to others.  Please post it as an answer below and then accept your own answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I second @Sparky, glad you figured it out. One bit of advice: WP uses "noConflict Mode" for a reason. Rather than disabling it, prepend your jQuery functions with `jQuery(` rather that `$(`, they will work then. Within functions defined like so, you can thereupon use `$(` as usual.

Comment: @Emerson What are you doing to load javascript? I'm having problems understanding the codex as well and would love to see an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to assume that wp_enqueue works because I am not seeing pitchforks and torches on the horizon.

Such a thing would upset many developers.

So given that, let's assume that it's never being called.

Try adding something like this to the function that's being called to unregister/register your new version of jQuery (not sure why you want to do this BTW).

```
<?php error_log( 'Something called me!' , 0 ); ?>
```

Then after you run your site and you expect your function to be called, go check your servers error log (/var/log/apache/yoursite-error.log or something) and see if that string shows up.

If it is showing up, we can move on to the next set of troubleshooting.

Comment: Troubleshooting hints should not be put in the answers section.  Please make this a more complete answer or move it up to the comments section on the OP.  Thanks.

Comment: UGH!

I THOUGHT jquery wasn't loading because I was seeing the error "$ is undefined" in the console. Turns out it was loading but in noConflict mode. It does mention this in the codex, but down below a bunch of examples for scriptaculous. Sort of frustrating. But oh well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For future reference, is there a way to view the error logs within Firebug or Chrome's developer panel? I often do my own version of this by just echoing strings, but it's a bit clunky.

Comment: You could just output some javascript on the expected function and do console.log( 'test' );

Comment: Yea. That's exactly what I had in mind. I was just curious if there was a PHP equivalent that wouldn't require printing markup or digging thru the log files. Maybe that's not doable.

Comment: You can try a basic echo statement echo "test"; and see if it's called. But sometimes filters/actions don't display output. I went with the safe bets :)

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

> Suppose you want to use the CDN copy of jQuery instead of WordPress’s,
>   add this code to your functions.php file.

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

Comment: That's from the official Wordpress documentation.  Without seeing your actual blog to determine what could be interfering, it's nearly impossible to help further.

Comment: I'm developing a theme locally. It's not live yet. But I started from a clean installation of WP3 and I'm just adding the code to the default twentyeleven theme. So there's really nothing to show. Right?

Comment: @Emerson,  but then there's also no way anyone could help, right?

Comment: I've asked and had answered many questions that pertained to projects that weren't live. I don't understand why this is not an appropriate question.

Comment: @Emerson, I did not say this was an inappropriate question.  I said it's nearly impossible to answer it without seeing your site.  How exactly are _we_ supposed to know what went wrong within _your_ project?  SO would become useless if the **Answers** sections were filled with nothing but guessing and speculation.

Comment: @Emerson Sparky's code snippet is not only from the wordpress codex, it does work. I am using this exact method on several production sites successfully. I see two possible causes for it not working: **1.** Your local environment does not connect to the net correctly. **2.** The version numbering (in the above and the codex) might be wrong. Check the [google libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery) - version 1.6 (see "older versions") is called "1.6.0" there and the newest is "1.6.4". Try substituting either for "1.6" in the above code.

Comment: @JohannesPille, I agree with most of your comment.  However, regarding your point #2, the above quoted jQuery 1.6 link is [perfectly valid](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js).  It links to the latest version within the 1.6 directory which is 1.6.4.

Comment: @Sparky Was guessing the last one - I am using "1.6.4" in my code - never tested "1.6". Could have been the culprit, would have been a stroke of luck for the OP if it was...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment but presume the opening question is too old to do so.

I hope I've quoted all the right people here and acknowledged their input.

---

I had the same issue as @Emerson for a while until I did the following and how have jQuery working /loading.

First I changed my JS code from $( to jQuery( as @Johannes Pille suggested in the opening bunch of comments. Information about the noConflict() which @Johannes Pille mentions can be found at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

That link to the codec is just for you @Emerson.. :P

So my code looks as follows - hope this helps someone.

JS Code

```
/**
 * navigation.js
 *
 * Handles toggling the navigation menu for small screens.
 */

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
    jQuery("#menu-header-menu").slideToggle("fast");
});
});
```

In my functions.php file

```
function toggle_menu(){
if(!is_admin()){
    //register the script location
    wp_register_script('navigation', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', 
        array('jquery'), '2.0.110526' );
    // enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script('navigation');
};
}
add_action('init', 'toggle_menu');
```

I found that telling Wordpress the version of jQuery to use, '2.0.110526' was **very** important. Without this it didn't work.

I didn't have to add any of the OP's examples of adding jQuery to the header.php or functions.php. As stated by many others Wordpress comes shipped with jQuery. I've found that you just need to tell Wordpress when and what version to use when registering your scripts in functions.php